# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?). when running ng test after upgrading to angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-runner

I'm right now upgrading my project from angular version 5.2 to angular version 7.2.

I ran the following commands:

1. Upgraded all angular packages package.json to ~7.2.0
2. ran `ng upgrade @angular/cli`
3. ran `ng upgrade @angular/core`
4. ran `ng test` and got the error:

> `Chrome 68.0.3440 (Windows 8.1.0.0) NdvAction ndv!!!! FAILED Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?). at syntaxError node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:2426:1) at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:18979:1) at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:18872:1) at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:18740:1) at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:18550:1) at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:18664:1 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:18652:1) at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:18550:1) Chrome 68.0.3440 (Windows 8.1.0.0): Executed 1 of 395 (1 FAILED) (skipped 394) ERROR (0.527 secs / 0.038 secs)`

I could minimal reproduce the issue on my project itself, couldn't reproduce it on an empty project, I created an empty service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class NdvAction {
}
```

with an empty test case:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NdvAction } from './ndv.action';

fdescribe('NdvAction', () => {
  let target: NdvAction;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [NdvAction]
    });
  });

  beforeEach(inject([NdvAction],
    (service: NdvAction) => {
      target = service;
    }));

  it('ndv!!!!', () => {});
});
```

and I've got the error, when I removed the beforeEach with the inject([NdvAction] part, the error disappeared.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong ? If you need any more details please let me know so that I'll add.
My package.json looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/store": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "~11.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "~4.0.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "cyb-core": "1.0.17-ng7",
    "shell-utils": "~2.1.0",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "json-typescript-mapper": "1.1.3",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "lodash-es": "4.16.0",
    "lodash.get": "4.4.2",
    "normalize.css": "4.2.0",
    "normalizr": "3.2.3",
    "primeng": "^5.2.4",
    "redux": "~4.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "~6.3.0",
    "sass-flex-mixin": "1.0.3",
    "string-template": "^1.0.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.27"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "2.2.4",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.120",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.12.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.46",
    "@types/node": "7.0.18",
    "codelyzer": "3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "3.0.2",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.0",
    "test-reducer": "^2.0.2"
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you check  if you have any circular dependency inside NdvAction service?

Comment: You may find some help in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55590935/cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-application-module-at-syntaxerror-compil/55598075.

Comment: This worked for me https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/573